How to evaluate $ \int_0^\infty \ln^3(1 - e^{-\pi x}) \tanh(\pi x) \, dx $

Question

How to evaluate
$$
\int_0^\infty \ln^3(1 - e^{-\pi x}) \tanh(\pi x) \, dx 
$$

My attempt

$$
\int_0^\infty \ln^3(1 - e^{-\pi x}) \tanh(\pi x) \, dx 
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(x)  \left(1 - (1 - x)^2\right)}{1 + (1 - x)^2} \, dx 
$$
$$
\text{(Substitute } u = 1 - e^{-\pi x}, \text{ which simplifies the integrand)}
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 \ln^3(x)  \left(\frac{1}{1 - x} - \frac{2(1 - x)}{1 + (1 - x)^2}\right) \, dx 
$$
Now,I am stuck or we simplify the expression by expanding  $1 - (1 - x)^2$?

Did you try using the Feynman trick?

With the help of WolframAlpha : $$\int_0^\infty \ln^3(1 - e^{-\pi x}) \tanh(\pi x) , dx =\frac{\pi^3}{15}-\frac{6}{\pi}\left(\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)+\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1-i}{2}\right) \right)$$ Li$_4$ is the polylogarithm function https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html .

Repeated I.B.P. yields for 1st integral \begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_1 &=& \int \frac{\log^3x}{1-x} dx=\
&=&-\log^3x\log(1-x)+3\int\frac{\log^2x \log(1-x)}xdx=\
&=&-\log^3x\log(1-x)-3\int\log^2xd\ \mbox{Li}_2(x)=\
&=&-\log^3x\log(1-x)-3\log^2x\mbox{Li}_2(x)+6\int\frac{\log x\mbox{Li}_2(x)}xdx=\
&=&-\log^3x\log(1-x)-3\log^2x\mbox{Li}_2(x)+6\int\log x d\ \mbox{Li}_3(x)=\
&=&-\log^3x\log(1-x)-3\log^2x\mbox{Li}_2(x)+ 6\log x \mbox{Li}_3(x)-6\int\frac{\mbox{Li}_3(x)}xdx=\
&=&-\log^3x\log(1-x)-3\log^2x\mbox{Li}_2(x)+6\log x \mbox{Li}_3(x)-6\mbox{Li}_4(x) + C.
\end{eqnarray}

Picking up from the OP's last step,
$$I= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 \ln^3(x)  \left(\frac{1}{1 - x} - \frac{2(1 - x)}{1 + (1 - x)^2}\right) \, dx$$
$$I= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 \ln^3(x)  \left(\frac{1}{1 - x}\right)\,dx -\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{(1 - x)\ln^3(x)}{x^2-2x+2} \, dx$$
We can use this below generalized formula for the first integral,

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ \ln^{n}(x)}{1-x} \ dx = (-1)^{n} n! \ \zeta(n+1)$$

$$I= \frac{-\pi^3}{15} -\color{red}{\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{(1 - x)\ln^3(x)}{x^2-2x+2} \, dx}$$
Integrating this red integral, is quite complicated, But i believe it goes somewhat this way;
Using the idea from here,
$$\frac{1-x}{x^2-2x+2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\cos\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^{n+1}$$
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^1 \ln^3(x)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\cos\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^{n+1}\right) \, dx $$
$$\implies \frac{2}{\pi}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cos\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^{n+1}\right)\int_0^1 x^n\ln^3(x) \, dx$$
Using this
$$\implies \frac{-12}{\pi}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cos\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^4}\right)\right)$$
$$I= \frac{-\pi^3}{15} +\color{red}{\frac{12}{\pi}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cos\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^4}\right)\right)}$$
Substituting $n+1=k$ in the summation to shift our index;
$$I= \frac{-\pi^3}{15} +\color{red}{\frac{12}{\pi}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)\right)}$$
We need the real part of our series,
$$I= \frac{-\pi^3}{15} +\color{red}{\frac{12}{\pi}\Re\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (e^{i
\frac{\pi}{4}})^k\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)\right)\right]}$$
Using the Euler's formula,
$$I= \frac{-\pi^3}{15} +\color{red}{\frac{12}{\pi}\Re\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^k}{k^4}\right]}$$
$$\boxed{I= \frac{-\pi^3}{15} +{\frac{12}{\pi}\Re\left[Li_4\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\right]}\approx -0.1733}$$

Which matches with this


\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \ln^3(1 - e^{-\pi x}) \tanh(\pi x) dx\\
=&  \ \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x\left(1 - (1 - x)^2\right)}{(1 + (1 - x)^2)(1-x)} \, dx \\
 = &\ \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 \ln^3x \left(\frac{1}{1 - x} - \frac{2(1 - x)}{1 + (1 - x)^2}\right) dx\\
 = &\ \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3x}{1 - x}dx -\frac{2}{\pi}  \Re \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3x}{1 + i-x}\, dx\\
=&-\frac{\pi^3}{15}+\frac{12}\pi \Re \ \text{Li}_4\left(\frac1{1+i}\right)
\end{align}

Wonderful solution!
